# Selecting parameters in String.format()

Tags: java, formatting

In `C#` you can specify which parameter is used for a formatted string with `para 2: {2}`. This allows for using parameters in arbitrary places and multiple times.

Is there a way to do this with standard java?

Comment: @RahulTripathi, yes I checked that again and hence i removed the flag.

Comment: @DeepikaRajani:- Appreciate that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You can define the argument's index, see the **Argument Index** section of the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

For instance:

```
//                 ┌ argument 3 (1-indexed)
//                 | ┌ type of String
//                 | |  ┌ argument 2
//                 | |  | ┌ type of decimal integer
//                 | |  | |  ┌ argument 1
//                 | |  | |  | ┌ type of decimal number (float)
//                 | |  | |  | |
System.out.printf("%3$s %2$d %1$f", 1.5f, 42, "foo");
```

**Output**

```
foo 42 1.500000
```

**Note**

The following idioms all share the same format definitions:

- `String#format`
- `PrintStream#printf`
- `Formatter#format`

Answer (score 4):

Yes. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax we can see that general formula of placeholders is

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

We are interested in this part

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So you can do it by using adding `x$` to your placeholder where `x` represents parameter number (indexed from 1) like

```
String.format("%2$s %1$s", "foo", "bar"); //returns `"bar foo"`
//              ^^   ^^     ^^^    ^^^
//               |    \_____/      |
//               |                 |
//               \_________________/
```

BTW: if you want to use formatting like `{x}` simply use `MessageFormat.format`

```
MessageFormat.format("{1} {0}", "foo", "bar") //result: "bar foo"
```

Comment: I was looking a solution you shared with MessageFormat. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

> Returns a formatted string using the specified format string and arguments.

Use:

```
String.format("%1$s", object);
```